# Observe values added to Set - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to observe values being added to a `Set` data-structure?

What i'm trying to achieve:

```
var storedStrings = Set<String>() {
    didSet (value) {
        // where value is a string that has been added to the Set
    }
}
```

Example:
`storedStrings.insert("hello")`
didSet called, as a new value has been added.

`storedString.insert("world")`
didSet called again.

`storedString.insert("hello")`
didSet not called, as the set already contains the string "hello"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a bit expensive, but you still can do something like:

```
var storedStrings = Set<String>() {
    didSet {
        if storedStrings != oldValue {
            print("storedStrings has changed")
            let added = storedStrings.subtracting(oldValue)
            print("added values: \(added)")
            let removed = oldValue.subtracting(storedStrings)
            print("removed values: \(removed)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `insert` function returns a tuple with the definition: `(inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element)`.

Therefore the check for a new unique element can be made on insertion instead of using `didSet`.

```
var storedStrings = Set<String>()

var insertionResult = storedStrings.insert("Hello")
if insertionResult.inserted {
    print("Value inserted") // this is called
}

insertionResult = storedStrings.insert("Hello")
if insertionResult.inserted {
    print("Value inserted") // this isn't called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own inserter for your set, which could emulate the use of a property observer, making use of the fact that the `insert` method of `Set` returns a tuple whose first member is `false` in case the element to be inserted is already present.

> ```
> func insert(Element)
> ```
>
> Inserts the given element in the set *if it is not already present.*

From [the language reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/set/1541375-insert).

E.g.:

```
struct Foo {
    private var storedStrings = Set<String>()

    mutating func insertNewStoredString(_ newString: String) {
        if storedStrings.insert(newString).0 {
            print("Inserted '\(newString)' into storedStrings")
        }
    }
}

var foo = Foo()
foo.insertNewStoredString("hello") // Inserted 'hello' into storedStrings
foo.insertNewStoredString("hello") 
foo.insertNewStoredString("world") // Inserted 'world' into storedStrings
```